# Changing rotational point

Tags: java, math, graphics, trigonometry, perspective

I am having an issue with my program; currently it rotates around a set point, and can rotate models around it. Of course, this is a problem as I want it to be a first-person perspective, and currently, it rotates around a point in front of the viewer, instead of the perspective of the viewer. Here is the trigonometric calculations:

```
protected void drawWireframe(Graphics g) {
            double theta = Math.PI * -azimuth / 180.0D;
            double phi = Math.PI * elevation / 180.0D;
            float cosT = (float) Math.cos(theta);
            float sinT = (float) Math.sin(theta);
            float cosP = (float) Math.cos(phi);
            float sinP = (float) Math.sin(phi);
            float cosTcosP = cosT * cosP;
            float cosTsinP = cosT * sinP;
            float sinTcosP = sinT * cosP;
            float sinTsinP = sinT * sinP;
            float near = 6.0F;
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {
                Point[] points = new Point[vertices.length];
                for (int j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
                    float x0 = -(tiles.get(i).getX() + xmod + vertices[j]
                            .getX());
                    float y0 = (tiles.get(i).getY() + ymod + vertices[j].getY());
                    float z0 = -(tiles.get(i).getZ() + zmod + vertices[j]
                            .getZ());

                    float x1 = cosT * x0 + sinT * z0;
                    float y1 = -sinTsinP * x0 + cosP * y0 + cosTsinP * z0;
                    float z1 = cosTcosP * z0 - sinTcosP * x0 - sinP * y0;

                    if (z1 + near > 0) {
                        x1 = x1 * near / (z1 + near);
                        y1 = y1 * near / (z1 + near);
                        points[j] = new Point((int) (Math.max(getWidth(),
                                getHeight()) / 2 - (Math.max(getWidth(),
                                getHeight()) / near) * x1), (int) (Math.max(
                                getWidth(), getHeight()) / 2 - (Math.max(
                                getWidth(), getHeight()) / near) * y1));
                    }
                }
          }
    }
```

How would I go about moving the rotational point without actually modifying the xmod, ymod and zmod (these are used for movements like jumping, walking, running, crouching... etc)

I know how to figure out how to get the new x, y and z positions, I just don't know how to apply them; if I add them to the mods, it creates a weird loop-d-loop. If I add them to the x1, y1, z1's it doesn't cover the z not rotating from the perspective.

Answer (score 1):

To change the rotation point, you effectively need three transforms:

1. Translate the coordinate system so that the rotation point becomes the origin.
2. Perform a rotation around the origin
3. Translate the coordinate system back again.

This can be factored a number of ways, but that's the basic priniciple: translate->rotate->translate.

Comment: This will still rotate about the same point; it sounds like he wants to move the actual rotation point.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: You're right, you effectively need to two translations.  Answer reworded accordingly.

Comment: Would like to point out: your perspective's position is not really available. I believe it is close to 6-7 tiles away from the origin.

Comment: @Legend: I'm not sure I understand.  You must know the position of the camera (viewer) in the world-coordinate system.  So you need to translate the world so that the camera is at the origin.

Comment: @Legend: I don't really want to download and run all your code.  Please try to explain better what it is that you don't understand.

Comment: @Legend: I'm sorry, I don't really know how to explain this any better (I'm not going to rewrite your code for you!).  I think you should take the advice in BlueRaja's answer, and read up about matrix transformations.

Answer (score 1):

The way you *"move the rotation point"* of an object is by translating the object so that the rotation point is at the origin; do the rotation; then translate the object back.  All of this is done in memory, between frames - the user never actually *sees* the object moving to the origin and back.

---

By the way, all this stuff is significantly easier if you understand [vectors](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors/u3l1a.cfm) and [matrix transformations](http://wally.cs.iupui.edu/n351/3D/matrix.html) - as you've seen yourself, without them the code can get out of hand.

Using vectors/matrices, all your code above could be reduced to only a few lines.